# how to sort the texts of xml nodes in groovy

Tags: xml, sorting, groovy

I have this sample XML below:

```
<VqlQueryRestResult>
<data>
    <row>
        <Field3>BBB</Field3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Field3>CCC</Field3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Field3>AAA</Field3>
    </row>
</data>
```

Tried the following Code but :

```
Node root = new XmlParser().parse(xml);
def orderNode = root.VqlQueryRestResult;
orderNode[0].children().sort(true) {it.item.Field3.text()}
```

I need to reorder it as below:

```
<VqlQueryRestResult>
    <data>
        <row>
            <Field3>AAA</Field3>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Field3>BBB</Field3>
        </row>
        <row>
            <Field3>CCC</Field3>
        </row>
    </data>
</VqlQueryRestResult>
```

I would like to now sort this XML so that it goes to the correct position, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with the code below:

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(msg);
root.data.each { it.children().sort { it.Field3.text() } }
```